# What topics does Elliptic curve cryptography lie under?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, computer-science, cryptography

I know this is a weird question to ask. Basically for my Math Internal Assessment, I want to explore Elliptic curve cryptography. (

Due to the lack of time, I'm unable to properly study it and I'm suppose to hand in a proposal very soon.

Therefore I was wondering what topics come under Elliptic curve cryptography?
I think the main topic is functions?

For example: If my topic was calculating surface area of an egg; I guess the main topic it would lie under would calculus & maybe algebra

Comment: for context, what stage are you at in your education?

Comment: @Moo. You are clearly not in the industry, or use the words "phased out" very loosely. ECDHE is extremely popular.

Comment: @Moo, link? Here are some small sites that use Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman Exchange: google.com, facebook.com, wikipedia.com You should probably forward your link to them too.

Comment: @πr8 I'm currently in Year 12 Doing IB. I'm Interested in this Topic as part of a compulsory extensive Math Exploration, where the student has to do a topic / solve a problem or anything related to Maths in detail. This assignment is to be carried on for about 3 - 5 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it under Number Theory. I would recommend [Ketheth Rosen's Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321500318) as it is a pleasure to read, even as an undergrad, and its section on ECC is written by Larry Washington, an expert on the subject matter.

To see this stuff is real and in use, from the linux command line if you type

```
openssl s_client -host website -port 443
```

You can see what cipher suite the website is using. Hit CTRL-C to break. For example

```
openssl s_client -host google.com -port 443
```

will contain in its extensive output

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellmen Exchange is being used so that the site and the user can have a shared secret.